# Node-mssql Hangs After Query

Tags: node.js, node-mssql

I am having an issue where I am running a node script to retrieve data from SQL Server.  It seems I am getting results, but no code is executed after the query is run.  Here is what I have so far for code:

```
var config = {
    user: 'blah',  
    password: 'blah',  
    server: 'blah',  
    database: 'blah'
};

sql.connect(config, err => {

    if(err) { console.log(err); }

    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.query('select * from products', function(err, data){
        console.log(data.recordset);
        ProcessData(data.recordset);                       
    });

});

sql.on('error', err => {
    console.log(err);    
});    

function ProcessData(results){
    for(var i; i < results.length - 1; i++){
        console.log(results[i].sku);
    }
}
```

Now, I see results in the terminal for console.log(data.recordset), but I never see any results in the terminal from the ProcessData function.  Is there something I am missing that is keeping my code from running correctly?  Thanks.

Wade

Comment: I'm stuck on this as well. Similar example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out.. You just need to close the connection.

```
sql.connect(config, err => {

    if(err) { console.log(err); }

    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.query('select * from products', function(err, data){
        console.log(data.recordset);
        ProcessData(data.recordset);  
        sql.close() // just close the connection and it will exit !

    });

});
```